# Filtering collection with collection of predicates and conforming to threshold

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, predicate

I'm stuck at one of exercises that I'm doing to get into functional programming a bit, so my main issue is how to count passed predicates on element of a collection and if it conform to given threshold than collect it to the final collection.

I know how to make it without threshold, and here is my solution:

```
List<String> filter(List<Predicate<String>> predicateList, List<String> stringList) {
    return stringList.stream()
                     .filter(predicateList.stream()
                                          .reduce(x -> !(x.isEmpty()), Predicate::and))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But what should I do while there is parameter which determines how many percent of predicates need to be passed to make string be collected, let's say the body of method could look like this:

```
List<String> filtrr(List<Predicate<String>> predicateList, List<String> stringList, Double threshold) {}
```

**EDIT:**
For example method should pass unit test like this:

```
@Test
void filtrrTest() {
    Double threshold = 0.65;

    Predicate<String> predicate = p -> p.contains("lorem");
    Predicate<String> predicate1 = p -> p.length() > 10;
    Predicate<String> predicate2 = p -> p.contains("sed");

    List<Predicate<String>> predicateList = Arrays.asList(predicate, predicate1, predicate2);

    String string = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sed";
    String string1 = "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod";
    String string2 = "ipsum";
    String string3 = "adipiscing elit";
    String string4 = "sed do eiusmod";

    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(string, string1, string2, string3, string4);
    List<String> expectedList = Arrays.asList(string, string1, string4);

    assertEquals(expectedList, ClassName.filtrr(predicateList, stringList, threshold));
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to say here.

Comment: if you're doing this "exercise" of yours online. then please post the description of it :).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner threshold is minimum percentage value of passed predicates for string (from stringList) to be collected to returned list.

Comment: @Aomine unfortunately it's not online, this is the way of friend of mine to make my life terrible. Step by step:
Filter list of strings with list of predicates -> Check how many predicates returned 'true' from test() -> if passed/predicatesList.size() > threshold -> collect

Comment: @saturator22 Right, now to make your post clearer please provide some sample data for `predicateList`, `stringList` and `threshold` specifying what data you expected to be returned.

Comment: @Aomine edited :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner will do, thank you !

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner i know, no hard feelings, every feedback is a good one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first create a generic utility method that checks whether a given element matches up to `threshold %` of the predicates:

```
public static <T> boolean matchingSome(
        T elem, 
        List<Predicate<T>> predicates, 
        double threshold) {

    long predsToMatch = (long) ((double) predicates.size() * threshold);

    long predsMatched = predicates.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.test(elem))
        .limit(predsToMatch) // this limit is to short-circuit as soon as
        .count();            // predsToMatch predicates evaluate to true

    return predsMatched == predsToMatch;
}
```

Note that I'm short-circuiting the stream as soon as `predsToMatch` predicates have evaluated to `true`. This is to avoid keep on evaluating further predicates.

Now simply collect all the strings for which the above method returns `true`:

```
List<String> result = stringList.stream()
    .filter(s -> matchingSome(s, predicateList, threshold))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: IIUC he needs the combined Predicate to be true if `threshold ` of the single predicates evaluate to true.

Comment: @daniu exactly, but thank you for your support Federico

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now i am thinking about fp in a different way ! Day has been saved !